# Как разделить строку по символу-якорю

Tags: java, строки

У меня есть строка, допустим `&atext1&btext2 &c- &{{#FFFFFF; #000000}}text3.`
То, что идет после `&` - это цвет. Он может быть в формате `&<символ>` или `&{{<hex через ;>}}`.
Как я могу разделить текст в массив, что бы он выглядел примерно так: `["&a", "text1", "&b", "text2 ", "&c", "- ", "&{{#FFFFFF; #000000}}", "text3."]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для разбиения по символу используется метод `String::split`, затем можно использовать обычные методы `String::substring` / `String.lastIndexOf`, чтобы определить пары, похожие на "ключ-значение":

```java
String[] result = Arrays.stream(str.split("&"))
    .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
    .flatMap(s -> s.lastIndexOf("}") == -1 
        ? Stream.of(s.substring(0, 1), s.substring(1))
        : Stream.of(s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf("}") + 1), s.substring(s.lastIndexOf("}") + 1))
    )
    .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
// -> [a, text1, b, text2 , c, - , {{#FFFFFF; #000000}}, text3.]
```

---

Или же можно определить регулярное выражение для каждой пары и использовать поток совпадений:
`&([^}&]+\}\}|.)([^&]+)`:

- `&` - начинается с символа `&`
- группа 1: `([^}&]+\}\}|.)` - непустая последовательность любых символов кроме `}` и `&`, ограниченная двумя закрывающими фигурными скобками ИЛИ один любой символ
- группа 2: `([^&]+)` - любые символы (хотя бы 1), кроме разделителя `&`

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&([^}&]+\\}\\}|.)([^&]+)");
String[] result2 = p.matcher(str)
    .results() // Stream<MatchResult>
    .flatMap(mr -> Stream.of(mr.group(1), mr.group(2)))
    .toArray(String[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result2));
// -> [a, text1, b, text2 , c, - , {{#FFFFFF; #000000}}, text3.]
```

Comment: А как при помощи регулярки можно сохранять знак &?

Comment: перенести его под скобку первой группы: `(&[^}&]+\\}\\}|.)([^&]+)`